# How to get form values and show in my html?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

i have a doubt, i have a form in which i want to get all values of that form through jquery and show it it in my div. how to do that,

i know how to get the values of a input field or any element like this

```
$("input").val();
```

but i dont know how to show it in my html..! and how to get multiple field values as well.. the above function get values of just "input" field, but i have text area too..!

here is my code snippits

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.radio-checked").hide();
    $("input[name$='custom']").click(function() {
        $("div.radio-checked").show();
        $( "#default" ).prop( "checked", false );
    });
    $("input[name$='standard']").click(function() {
        $("div.radio-checked").hide();
        $( "#custom" ).prop( "checked", false );
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

audio,
canvas,
iframe,
img,
svg,
video {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #11999E;
}

section.home {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #40514E;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #ffffff;
}

section.features {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #11999E;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  /* 3/16 */
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
}
h1 .xl {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  /* 1.5/16 */
}

input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="number"], input[type="date"], textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #11999E;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="number"], input[type="date"] {
  height: 40px;
}

input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="email"]:hover, input[type="tel"]:hover, input[type="number"]:hover, input[type="date"]:hover, textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #30E3CA;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #30E3CA;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #11999E;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2em 1em 2.5em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 2em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before,
input[type="radio"] + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #11999E;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.2em white, inset 0 0 0 2em #ffffff;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:hover:before {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.3em white, inset 0 0 0 2em #30E3CA;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.2em white, inset 0 0 0 2em #11999E;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -55px;
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -90px;
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  /* At the top of the tooltip */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.radio-checked {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .radio-checked {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.radio-checked input[type="text"], .radio-checked input[type="number"] {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #11999E;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}
.radio-checked label {
  float: left;
}
.radio-checked input[type="text"]:hover, .radio-checked input[type="number"]:hover, .radio-checked textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #30E3CA;
}
.radio-checked textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #11999E;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://emjimadhu.com/grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="home">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="name">Enter Your Full name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" required></input>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="email">Enter your Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="name" placeholder="Your Email" required></input>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="phone">Enter Your Phone Number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="name" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required></input>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="address">Enter Your Address:</label>
                        <textarea name="name" id="address" rows="8" cols="40" placeholder="Your Address" required></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="pickup">Date of Courier</label>
                        <input type="date" name="name" id="pickup"></input>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <span>Select your type of Courier:</span><br>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="standard" id="default" required></input>
                            <label for="default">Standard</label>
                            <div class="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i>
                                <span class="tooltiptext">A Standard courier is picking up a courier from you.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="custom" id="custom" required></input>
                            <label for="custom">Custom</label>
                            <div class="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i>
                                <span class="tooltiptext">A Custom Courier is type of gift where we buy products based on your interest and we deliver it to your recipent.</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio-checked">
                                <label for="product-name">Name of your Product?</label>
                                <input type="text" id="product-name" name="which-cat" data-require-pair="#custom" required>
                                <label for="product-cost">Approximate Cost of the product?</label>
                                <input type="number" id="product-cost" name="which-cat" data-require-pair="#custom" required>
                                <label for="product-address">Where to Buy/Pickup the product?</label>
                                <textarea name="name" id="product-address" rows="8" cols="40" data-require-pair="#custom" required></textarea>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="output" class="col-md-6">
              <p>name:</p>
              <p>
                number:
              </p>
              <p>
                email:
              </p>
              <p>
                address:
              </p>
              <p>
                date:
              </p>
              <p>
                courier type:
              </p>
              
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

i want to get all the fields values and show in the corresponding fields on the #output div element.

and i just have on click function to show additional fields for the radio buttons, i want to show that field as well, if i click on radio button.

Comment: you can use .html()

Comment: source:-http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_input_examples.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$('#contact-submit').click(function (){
   var formKeyValue=null;
   var string="";
   formKeyValue = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
   $(formKeyValue ).each(function(index, obj){
     string = string+"<p>"+obj.name+' : '+obj.value+"</p><br>"
   });
   $("#output").html("");
   $("#output").html(string);
});
```

Note: **The name attribute of all input tag should be unique/different.**

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="email">Enter your Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required/>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: *"The name attribute of all input tag should be unique/different."* you're mixing `name=` with `id=` .  name does not need to be unique and, in many cases, must **not** be.  (but the code's good :) )

Comment: well that doesn't need not to be unique but in this case i am considering name attribute for label so it must be unique and to send same form to controller  it suppose to be unique

Comment: @rakesh thank you so much.. it works perfectly fine.. but only one doubt.. as you can see in the example i gave, i have radio buttons.. for 'custom' radio button i have additional fields, is there any way, the output will only show the fields which are filled? dont show the empty fields? and second one is it displays radio button out put as 'standard=on'.. instead of this can i show values which are added to the radio utton? say for example a numeric value? im really sorry, im new to jquery, thats why these much questions..!

Comment: @Madhu in input type="radio" add value='standard' so that wont give 'standard=on' and replace 'string = string+"<p>"+obj.name+' : '+obj.value+"</p><br>";' with ' if(obj.value!=''){string = string+"<p>"+obj.name+' : '+obj.value+"</p><br>";}'